# How do you set specific bits on a binary number in IA32 or x86 ISA?

Tags: x86

I've used another processor that had something like BIS to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OR` instructions to set specific bits with a bit pattern and `AND` to clear them (using the one's complement of the bit pattern you would use to set them). The bit patterns can be adjusted to set and clear multiple bits at a time.

For example, let's say you're dealing with 8-bit values and you want to set bits 4 and 3 (`x` means it could be either `0` or `1`):

```
    xxxx xxxx
 OR 0001 1000
  = xxx1 1xxx
```

Then, to clear bits 7, 6, 2 and 0:

```
    xxx1 1xxx
AND 0011 1010
  = 00x1 10x0
```

`OR` and `AND` should be supported on just about *every* CPU out there. I can't guarantee that but I've never seen one without it (and I've seen quite a few).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the normal `AND` and `OR`, there are also `BTS` (set), `BTC` (complement), and `BTR` (reset) that do test-and-X operations on single bits (plus `BT` which is just the test).